# Role-based routing in LoginController (Auth)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

In my Laravel 5.3 setup, I am using [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer) package, and I defined two roles, `admin` and `customer`. When logged in, customers are redirected to `/home`, as specified in `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` under `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`. Now, if a user with the role of an `admin` logs in, he is **also** redirected to `/home` because `$redirectTo` does not make any distinction between user roles. My goal here is to redirect admin users to **`/admin/home`** instead.

What is the best solution to handle this? Here is my attempt.

In `web.php` routes, outside of any middleware groups:

```
Route::get('/home', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) { // http://myapp.dev/home
    if (Auth::user()->isA('customer')) // -> goto HomeController@index
        return app()->make('\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController')->index($request);
    else if (Auth::user()->isAn('admin')) // -> redirect
        return redirect('/admin/home');
    else
        abort(403);
})->middleware('auth');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'Admin\HomeController@index');
});
```

Alternatively, this can can be done in a middleware, as well:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('auth', 'role');

// in VerifyRole.php middleware...    
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAn('admin')) {
        return redirect('/admin/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This would work, but it's not *scalable* if more roles are added. I am sure there must be an elegant built-in way to accomplish this. So the question is, **how do I route users to their proper dashboard** (i.e. `home`) **based on their role?**

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `authenticated()` method in your class `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` as:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->isA('customer'))
        return redirect('/home');
    else if ($user->isAn('admin'))
        return redirect('/admin/home');
}
```

Or

You can override the `redirectPath()` method as:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (auth()->user()->isA('customer'))
      return '/home';
    else if (auth()->user()->isAn('admin'))
      return '/admin/home';
}
```

Comment: Is this going to break any built-in logic that those methods come with by default?

Comment: No, it will not break anything.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but could you please check out my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201788/identifying-and-persisting-guest-users-in-laravel), it's about identifying guest users in Laravel. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.3, you can override `sendLoginResponse()` method in `AuthController.php` to be able to redirect users to a different routes after login.